# setAttribute iFrame name and Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Here is a simple setAttribute for an iFrame to append a name.

Issue is that the below code works great in all browsers except Chrome.

```
<iframe id="frame" frameborder="0" src="http://website.ca/"></iframe>
```

Parent javascript:

```
(function() {
    var newFrameName = "hello";
    document.getElementById("frame").setAttribute("name", newFrameName);

})();
```

in the iFrame:

```
    var iframeName = window.name;
    alert (iframeName );
```

Alert calls "Hello" in all browsers, Chrome calls "frame" -- which is the ID of the iFrame.
looking at source (through the elements inspector), in Chrome, I see the correct name for the iFrame: name="Hello" ... but the alert calls the id.

why would that be? I'm i missing anything?

Comment: also, when adding blank name to the iframe: <iframe name="" id="frame" frameborder="0" src="http://website.ca/"></iframe>

the alert calls blank.

Comment: in case when `<iframe name="name1" id="frame" frameborder="0" src="website.ca/"></iframe>` what alert calls?

Comment: and try `var iframeName = parent.document.getElementById("frame").name;     alert (iframeName );`

Comment: When the name is set in the iframe, eg. name="name1", Chrome will call name1. Hte above did not seem to do the trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creating iframe by createElement fixes the issue:

```
 function createFrame() {
        frame= document.createElement("iframe");
        frame.setAttribute("src", "https://website.ca/");
        frame.setAttribute("name", "Hello");
        frame.setAttribute("id", "frame");
        frame.frameBorder = 0;
        frame.style.width = 100 + "%";
        frame.style.height = 2300 + "px";
        document.getElementById("iframeHolder").appendChild(frame);

    }
    createFrame();

<div id="iframeHolder"> </div>
```

Bit of a hack, but it works for this situation.

Answer (score 2):

6 and a half years later I ran into the same problem.

It seems that Chrome sets the window.name property once and doesn't update it when the enclosing iFrame's name (either property or attribute) is updated.

Setting the window.name directly does work however.

So, changing the OP's example from:

```js
(function() {
    var newFrameName = "hello";
    document.getElementById("frame").setAttribute("name", newFrameName);
})();
```

into

```js
(function() {
    var newFrameName = "hello";
    document.getElementById("frame").name = newFrameName; // keep for other browsers
    document.getElementById("frame").contentWindow.name = newFrameName;
})();
```

works...